# View private YouTube videos using HTML 5 player

Tags: asp.net, html, youtube-api

I am embedding YouTube videos into my ASP.net website. 
To enable viewing on iphones I have used the HTML5 iframe as follows:

```
<div id="ytplayer"></div>

<script>
  // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
  // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: 'OUNRGC2F7sI'
});
```

}

All my videos are private so the player will appear and say "This video is private".
If I have logged into my YouTube account in the web browser then I can view the video.
How do I pass e.g. username and password (Or a developer key) to allow me to view private videos??

Comment: Can't you set the video to 'unlisted' instead of 'private'? I don't think you can programmatically authenticate to play a private video, it requires that you login in the browser.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid setting them to unlisted as I want to keep them private to people to log into my own website (And not allow people to copy the url) .  But I will use this method if I cannot find another way.  Thanks.